# Extract a single column from list of data frames with different lengths

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

(this is my first question so please be kind)

I have a list of data frames with different row lengths. I want to extract the same column from each data frame, and then bind these columns together while KEEPING the original column names (each column has a different name and different length; but same position respectively).

I've made an example: (and yes, I need to keep the character names with awkward spaces)

```
b = data.frame('a test' = c('a 1','a 2','a 3'), 
               'b' = c('b1','b2','b3'), 
                'c' = c('c1','c2','c3'))

c = data.frame('x test' = c('a 11','a 12'), 
               'y' = c('b11','b12'), 
               'z' = c('c11','c12'))

l = list(b,c)

> l
[[1]]
  a.test  b  c
1    a 1 b1 c1
2    a 2 b2 c2
3    a 3 b3 c3

[[2]]
  x.test   y   z
1   a 11 b11 c11
2   a 12 b12 c12
```

From here, I want to extract columns 'a test' and 'x test' and have them keep their names so try:

```
l = lapply(l,function(x) x[,1])
> l
[[1]]
[1] "a 1" "a 2" "a 3"

[[2]]
[1] "a 11" "a 12"

final = cbind(l)
> final
     l          
[1,] character,3
[2,] character,2
```

The problem is extracting the columns with `lapply()` does not keep the column names, and then trying to use `cbind()` ends up not extracting the columns into a useable data frame.

I'm sure there is a whole lot I'm missing despite hours searching Stackoverflow, so thank you for your help!

To edit in response to comments, thank you (Oct 24 2022):
My desired output is 'side by side' columns using something like `cbind()`, not binding the rows with `rbind()`.

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
> output
  a.test x.test
1    a 1   a 11
2    a 2   a 12
3    a 3
```

The hard part is needing to bind columns of different lengths while keeping the unique names for each one.

Hope this makes it more clear! Thanks!

Comment: Wellcome, TBlock. Please add an example of your desired output, based on your eamples, in order to clarify. It can be a data.frame.

Comment: Did you want to bind columns by ‘stacking’ or ‘side by side’? Your post makes me think you want stacking but I see you used ```cbind()``` and not ```rbind()```. Maybe I misinterpreted!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I edited the question and added desired output. I do need to use something like cbind() since columns need to be 'side by side'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, not knowing the exact desired format of the output:

First write a function to extract the first column of a `data.frame` and output its `name` in one column and the values in another.

Then use `lapply` and pipe it into `do.call("rbind")`.

```r
names_value_tbl <- function(x) {
  df_vals <- x[[1]]
  col_nm <- names(x)[1]
  data.frame(col_name = col_nm, value = df_vals)
}

lapply(l, names_value_tbl) |> 
  do.call("rbind", arg = _)
#>   col_name value
#> 1   a.test   a 1
#> 2   a.test   a 2
#> 3   a.test   a 3
#> 4   x.test  a 11
#> 5   x.test  a 12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For a none-pipe approach see below:

```r
l2 <- lapply(l, names_value_tbl) 

final <- do.call("rbind", arg = l2)
```

The OPs data:

```r
b = data.frame('a test' = c('a 1','a 2','a 3'), 
               'b' = c('b1','b2','b3'), 
               'c' = c('c1','c2','c3'))

c = data.frame('x test' = c('a 11','a 12'), 
               'y' = c('b11','b12'), 
               'z' = c('c11','c12'))

l = list(b,c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited the question and added desired output since it was not clear. I do need to use something like cbind() since columns need to be 'side by side' rather than rbind(). If you have some more advice it would be much appreciated!